# Perk in evaluation of Boolean variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have this slightly peculiar situation, a boolean statement I have is giving me two different evaluations, in the `alert` and `if` operator.

```
var test = new Boolean(homePageNonActive && ((firstTime && homePageHash) || (!firstTime && !homePageHash)));
alert(homePageNonActive && ((firstTime && homePageHash) || (!firstTime && !homePageHash))); // GIVES ME FALSE
alert(test); // GIVES ME TRUE ??? WHY?

if(test){
    alert(homePageNonActive); // GIVES ME TRUE
    alert(firstTime); // GIVES ME TRUE
    alert(homePageHash); // GIVES ME FALSE
}
```

Comment: no, we have one that wasn't defined as a boolean `var homePageNonActive = homePageTarget.hasClass("nonactive-pane");`

Comment: `var homePageHash = new Boolean(window.location.hash == '' || window.location.hash == '#');`
and also
`var firstTime = true;`
But those are both Boolean

Comment: [seems to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tkhy4/) given that all values are boolean. there must be something else mixed in your variables.

Comment: Can we see the assignment lines for all three variables? Also, can you create alert(typeof var); lines?

Comment: Joseph, maybe i'm going slightly mad or am extremely tired, but if `test` is false why are we getting the additional 3 alerts?

Comment: Why are you creating `new Boolean`s???

Comment: @albelito here is the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/Db557/

Comment: @Mohammad Did you see Joseph's post?

Comment: Yes I did and I just tested it as well, it was the `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to [work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Tkhy4/) as long as you use boolean primitives.

But the issue is that you are mixing Boolean objects (`homePageHash`) with boolean primitives (`homePageNonActive` and `firstTime`). The reason why `test` is "true" is because a "Boolean object false" is "truthy".

> [Boolean object is not the same as a boolean primitive.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
>
> Any object whose value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement.

```
var x = new Boolean(false),
    y = false; 

if (x) {/*this code is executed*/}
if (y) {/*this code is NOT executed*/}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my understanding of defining primitive Boolean variables was obviously wrong!